# Adding axhline to logistic growth model plot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to add the axhline to the plot legend alongside P(0)=900,000. It shows accordingly in jupyter notebook, but when I use plt.savefig(), it only saves the plot without the legend. Where did I go wrong here?

[image]

Also, I'm aware my code is quite messy. Is there a way I can make this more tidy?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# creating vectors X and Y
t = np.linspace(-25,25,100)
y = [1072764*np.exp(0.2311*t) / (0.19196+np.exp(0.2311*t)) for t in t]
 
#fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
# Create the plot
plt.plot(t, y, linestyle = '-',label = 'P(0)=900,000')
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.title("Logistic Growth Model $P(0)=\dfrac{1,072,764e^{0.2311(0)}}{0.19196+e^{0.2311(0)}}$")

# plot parameters
plt.grid()
plt.axhline(y=1072764, color='r', linestyle='--', label = 'P=1,072,764')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') 
plt.savefig('logistic', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')

# show the plot
plt.legend(loc='lower right'); plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to put the call to `savefig` after the call to `legend`.

Comment: 1. You should not be looping through the numpy `t` array to create `y`, just do `y = 1072764*np.exp(0.2311*t) / (0.19196+np.exp(0.2311*t))`. 2. Why are you labeling the titling the plot with `P(0)` rather than `P(t)`? The title should probably use the generic `t` and the blue line legend can be kept the same (assuming you will be plotting other lines with different `P(0)` values.

Comment: To generalize RuthC's excellent comment, you can generally think of a cell in a Jupyter `.ipynb` file running with a Python-based kernel as being just a more convenient way to send stuff to Python. In the most basic way you'd interact with Python would be on the command line after invoking [the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) (sometimes called the Python console). That works line by line as you enter things. For the most part you can think of a Jupyter `.ipynb` cell as working along the same line by line basis, and so you want do set up steps first ...

Comment: <continued> and then when things are prepared the way you want, you'd initiate the step that takes pictures. Generally at the end. For plotting the time to do that step would traditionally be right before the `plt.show()` line (or equivalent if you are using a non-Matplotlib-based plotting package). For the most part, what happens on the Python side if oblvious to whether there is a cell-based unit or line by line. **In modern Jupyter, you don't need the `plt.show()` anymore as Jupyter tries to be smart and detect you made a plot object in the cell and display it. However, I see that ...

Comment: <continued> Jupyter doing that may be confusing in some ways because it may seem things act with the cell as a unit and you may expect the `plt.savefig()` to also match up to what the cell overall specifies as well but that isn't how it presently works. You can just think of the `plt.show()` step as being optional as a convenience and that overall things still occur in steps from top to bottom.